# Change label inner text that contains link using Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a label that contains a link like following:

```
<label id="textlabel" > <a href="#"  id="testlink">data</a> </label>
```

I am trying to use Ajax to change label text, but it does not work.

For testing purposes, it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ54g/120/) but it does not work on my web page (the web page is brand new without anything else).

```
$('#testlink').click(function(){
    $('#testlabel').text("new data");
});
```

JavaScript:

```
function myfunc(clicked_id) {

            var label = document.getElementById(clicked_id).parentElement;
            var params = "{'orderid':'" + clicked_id + "'}";
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("orderid", params);
            alert("test");

            $("'#" + clicked_id + "'").click(function () {
                $.ajax
                       ({
                           url: 'Handler.ashx',
                           data: fd,
                           processData: false,
                           contentType: false,
                           type: 'POST',
                           success: function (result) {
                               $("'#"+label.id+"'").text(result);
                               }
                       })
            });
        }
```

Update:

1. the following ajax works in general

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function myfunc(clicked_id) {
       var params = "{'orderid':'" + clicked_id + "'}";
       var label = document.getElementById(clicked_id).parentElement;

       $("#"+label.id).click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Handler.ashx",
               data: clicked_id,
               success: function (result) {
                   $("#" + label.id).text(result);
                         }          
           }); });
   }
   ```
2. i spent so much time to pinpoint issue and now i think the issue is found at autogenerated elements. for example

   ```
   <table>
   <tr><td><label id="lbl" style="background-color:yellow">
   <a href="#" onclick="myfunc(this.id)" id="00000">Label</a>
   </label></td></tr>
   @for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
    <tr><td>
   <label id="lbl+@i" style="background-color:yellow">
   <a href="#" onclick="myfunc(this.id)" id="@i">Label</a>
    </label></td></tr>
   }
   </table>
   ```

ajax only changes first label' text but not other auto generated links and labels.
the following part does not run when clicking on auto generated links

```
            $("#"+label.id).click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Handler.ashx",
                data: clicked_id,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#" + label.id).text(result);
                          }          
            }); });
```

Update：

Finally I found what went wrong. it is the label ids I used. they all have "+" after changing to "_", my app works fine now.

thanks to all who helped

Comment: just add a console.log(label.id); in your success event handler to see if the label object is there.

Comment: $("'#"+label.id+"'") is not correct: it should be "#" + label.id -- without ' -- you add the ' characters to the string

Comment: where should console.log(label.id) go into ?

Comment: after `success: function (result) {` -- but the string in $(...) is wrong as I stated in my comment above

Comment: i tried with  $("#" + clicked_id) and  $("#" + label.id).text(result), still not working

Comment: added now it is success: function (result) {                                   console.log(label.id)
 $("#" + label.id).text(result);
    }      dont see anything in chrome

Comment: okay, this line is also wrong (event handler on wrong id): `$("'#" + clicked_id + "'").click(function () {` ---> should be `$("#" + clicked_id).click(function () {`

Comment: i did change that too

Comment: Ok, it's better if I prepare a jsfiddle for you

Comment: Btw, I think the whole setup is wrong, you don't need a <label> tag around your link. Why?

Comment: label is nested in table cell for displaying purpose

Comment: Here: http://jsbin.com/etomof/1/edit

Comment: regardless i think js does not even send out any data

Comment: your code works, so problem must be the ajax part

Comment: Are your <a> id numbers? That may be a problem...

Comment: what do u mean ?? all <a> has dynamic generated id and they are numbers with 8 digits. is this a problem?

Comment: ids must begin with a letter:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: oh, but i have no problem reference to those ids. but that could be, let me try

Comment: i changed ids to id+xxxx (x is int) and still no data sent out to handler, in fact, i tested ur code with int ids, your code works

Comment: tested with ajax, it works now in general, but it still does not work with the elements generated for some reason,

Comment: ok i tested a few times more, now it seems ajax does not fire with automatically generated links, is that the way supposed to be?

Comment: The html page and the JS dom etc. does not know if tag are created programmatically or with static html code. The problem must be somewhere else. Try to go step by step and add some console.log statements to see if the code is executed. Or debug in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update after the question's code was changed**

There's a glitch in

```
success: function (result) {
    $("'#"+label.id+"'").text(result) 
}
```

should be

```
success: function (result) {
    $("#"+label.id).text(result) 
}
```

Also, to test if the label object is there, you could add

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(label); // DON'T FORGET TO REMOVE THIS LINE LATER BEFORE DEPLOYING
    $("#"+label.id).text(result) 
}
```

---

Maybe because in your test function you've **misspelled** the label's id `textlabel` as `testlabel`

in

```
$('#testlink').click(function(){
    $('#testlabel').text("new data");
});
```

?

Then in your real code:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#label.id).text(result);
}
```

`#label.id` is

1. not the correct jQuery selector. It should be `'#textlabel'`
2. It's missing the closing '

Answer (score 1):

Hey If you want to update all label text containing links please try this code
I also update your demo link please refer

```
$('[id*="test"]').text("ddaadfa");
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/uQ54g/121/)

If you are using ajax then you have to use this code in success block to change text of link

```
success: function (result) {
    $('[id*="test"]').text("ddaadfa");
}
```

Comment: I will try, but what is that "*" used for?  Why do we need to use [ ] in this case?

Comment: Just to clarify all label has different ids, not same ids

Comment: if i want to use label.id variable in this context, how should i write this? is it $('[id*="+label.id+"]')?

Comment: Cool No probs if you have different ids of each label,use this code $('label').text("ddaadfa"); this code will change all label text whether ids are same or not.